# Is it possible to Pause this animation on mouseenter in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

I am learning Javascript. I have this code that slides images from their default positions to another position, then back to the default positions with a timer of 3 seconds. Two functions were written which made the codes run endlessly. But I will like to pause the animation when a mouse enters or on placed on a button I placed below the slider. And when the mouse leaves, the animation continues. Is this possible with this code?

Javascript code:

```
var section5slides = document.querySelector('.section5slides')
var section5slidersa = document.getElementById("section5slidersa");
var section5slidersb = document.getElementById("section5slidersb");
var section5slidersc = document.getElementById("section5slidersc");
var interval = 3000;

var rightBtn = document.getElementById("rightBtn")

slideRight();
function slideLeft() {
section5slidersa.style.left = " -500px";
section5slidersb.style.left = "-500px";
section5slidersc.style.left = "540px";
setTimeout(slideRight, interval);
}



function slideRight() {
section5slidersc.style.left = "1190px";
section5slidersb.style.left = "0px";
section5slidersa.style.left = " 0px";
setTimeout(slideLeft, interval);
}
```

As you can see, the first function timeout into the second function, and the second function time out into the first function. This creates an infinite slide that I wanted. Is there a way to add `clearTimeOut` on `mouseover` or `mouseenter` when the mouse is placed on the button with an Id name 'rightBtn' to stop the animation and continue when the mouse leaves the button?

Thank you very much.

Comment: do it with css, you also have lot of flexibility about looping pausing resuming etc. plus, while doing animations in js, do not use setTimeout but requestAnimationFrame

Comment: Thank you for your response. The timeout was used to create a loop effect due to the nature of the slides. The slide is made of three images only. At function Right, the images moved to given positions and at Function left, the images returned to their default position. setTimeOut was used to create the loop.

Comment: @Kingsley please add your html/css code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made an example with two slides for you. Tried to keep your original code as much as possible.

The `animationPaused` variable is the key to your question on how to pause slider animation using `mouseover`/`mouseout` event listeners.

```js
var status_text = document.getElementById('status_text');

var section5slides = document.querySelector('.section5slides')
var section5slidersa = document.getElementById("section5slidersa");
var section5slidersb = document.getElementById("section5slidersb");
var interval = 3000;

var rightBtn = document.getElementById("rightBtn")

var animationPaused = false;

function slideLeft() {
  setTimeout(slideRight, interval);

  if (animationPaused)
    return;

  section5slidersa.style.left = "0px";
  section5slidersb.style.left = "500px";
}

function slideRight() {
  setTimeout(slideLeft, interval);

  if (animationPaused)
    return;

  section5slidersa.style.left = "-500px";
  section5slidersb.style.left = "0px";
}

rightBtn.addEventListener('mouseover', function(e) {
  animationPaused = true;
  status_text.innerText = 'Animation Paused';
});

rightBtn.addEventListener('mouseout', function(e) {
  animationPaused = false;
  status_text.innerText = 'Animation Resumed';
});

slideLeft();
```

```css
.container {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 500px;
}

.section5slides {
  width: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.slide {
  position: absolute;
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  background: gray;
  transition: left 500ms;
  padding: 20px;
}

#section5slidersb {
  background: red;
}

#rightBtn {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="section5slides">
    <div id="section5slidersa" class="slide">Slide #1</div>
    <div id="section5slidersb" class="slide">Slide #2</div>
  </div>
  <button id="rightBtn">The Right Button (pause animation)</button>
  <div id="status_text">Animation Running</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This also looks helpful. I have been able to solve my challenge using a link provided by another user here. I read article there and was able to solve the problem. Thank you once again for your help.

Comment: You're welcome. You can mark my answer as accepted - click on the checkmark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.